# Error： All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I use the Pipeline of sklearn, it's working well sometimes, but it shows error most of the time.

I don`t know why. Please help me. Thanks.
The sklearn version is 0.21.2.

**Error message :**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/workspace/pycharm/machine-learning-1/多项式回归Pipline.py", line 18, in 
>       ("lin_reg", LinearRegression())
>     File "D:\develop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 135, in **init**
>       self._validate_steps()
>     File "D:\develop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 185, in _validate_steps
>       "'%s' (type %s) doesn't" % (t, type(t)))
>   TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False)' (type ) doesn't

**And my Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

x = np.random.uniform(-3, 3, size=100)
X = x.reshape(-1, 1)
y =  0.5 * x * x + 3 * x + np.random.normal(0, 1 , 100)


# pipleLine 写法
pip = Pipeline({
    ("ployFeature", PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)),
    ("std_scaler", StandardScaler()),
    ("lin_reg", LinearRegression())
})

pip.fit(X, y)
y_predict2 = pip.predict(X)

plt.plot(np.sort(x), y_predict2[np.argsort(x)], color="green")
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Error should be formatted as code, and not truncated

Answer (score 0):

Your Pipeline is wrong, you should write like this:

```
pip = Pipeline([
    ("ployFeature", PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)),
    ("std_scaler", StandardScaler()),
    ("lin_reg", LinearRegression())
])
```

Comment: note: pipeline entries should be enclosed by [], not by {}